# An application that compares two lists of byte strings

Tags: bitwise, rust

I am a beginner in Rust, and I am trying to write a program that compares  common bits between two lists of bits. The program below does that (with the variable names indicating the domain of application). I would appreciate a code review by anyone who might point out idiomatic and concise ways of accomplishing the same.

```
extern crate getopts;
extern crate num_bigint;
extern crate num_traits;
extern crate rand;

use num_bigint::BigUint;
use rand::distributions::{IndependentSample, Range};
use num_traits::FromPrimitive;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::iter::repeat;
use getopts::Options;
use std::env;

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyOptions {
    mutantlen: u64,
    nmutants: u64,
    ntests: u64,
    nfaults: u64,
    nchecks: u64,
    nequivalents: u64,
}

impl ToString for MyOptions {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        return format!("data/mutantlen={:?}/nequivalents={:?}/nmutants={:?}/nfaults={:?}/ntests={:?}/nchecks={:?}/",
                         self.mutantlen, self.nequivalents, self.nmutants,
                         self.nfaults, self.ntests, self.nchecks);
    }
}

fn genbits(bitlen: u64, nflipped: u64) -> BigUint {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let faulty_bits: u64 = Range::new(1, nflipped + 1).ind_sample(&mut rng);
    let mut m: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_usize(0).unwrap();
    for _ in 0..faulty_bits {
        let pos: usize = Range::new(0, bitlen).ind_sample(&mut rng) as usize;
        let one: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_usize(1).unwrap();
        let fault = one << pos;
        m |= fault;
    }
    return m;
}

fn gen_lst(num: u64, len: u64, nflipped: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    return (0..num).map(|_| genbits(len, nflipped)).collect(); //::<Vec<_>>
}

fn gen_mutants(nmutants: u64, mutantlen: u64, nfaults: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    return gen_lst(nmutants, mutantlen, nfaults);
}

fn gen_tests(ntests: u64, mutantlen: u64, nchecks: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    return gen_lst(ntests, mutantlen, nchecks);
}

fn kills(test: &BigUint, mutant: &BigUint) -> bool {
    return (test & mutant) > FromPrimitive::from_usize(0).unwrap();
}

fn zeros(size: usize) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    repeat(FromPrimitive::from_usize(0).unwrap())
        .take(size)
        .collect()
}

fn mutant_killed_by(m: &BigUint, tests: &Vec<BigUint>) -> usize {
    return tests.iter().filter(|t| kills(&t, m)).count();
}

fn mutant_killscore(
    _opts: &MyOptions,
    mutants: &Vec<BigUint>,
    equivalents: &Vec<BigUint>,
    my_tests: &Vec<BigUint>,
) -> HashMap<usize, usize> {
    return mutants.iter().chain(equivalents.iter())
        .map(|m| mutant_killed_by(m, my_tests))
        .enumerate().collect();
}

fn do_statistics(opts: &MyOptions, mutant_kills: &HashMap<usize, usize>) -> () {
    let mut ntests = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..1001 {
        let mut e = 0;
        let mut a = 0;
        let mut s = 0;
        for (_m, k) in mutant_kills {
            if *k == i {
                e += 1;
            }
            if *k >= i {
                a += 1;
            }
            if *k <= i {
                s += 1;
            }
        }
        ntests.push((i, a, s, e))
    }
    let fname = format!("{:}kills.csv", opts.to_string());
    let mut f = File::create(&fname).expect(&format!("Unable to create file: {}", &fname));

    f.write_all("ntests, atleast, atmost, exactly\n".as_bytes())
        .expect("Unable to write data");
    for &(i, a, s, e) in &ntests {
        let data = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}\n", i, a, s, e);
        f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect();

    let ref _program = args[0];
    let mut opts = Options::new();
    opts.optopt("l", "mutantlen", "length of a mutant", "mutantlen");
    opts.optopt("m", "nmutants", "number of mutants", "nmutants");
    opts.optopt("t", "ntests", "number of tests", "ntests");
    opts.optopt("f", "nfaults", "maximum number of faults per mutant", "nfaults");
    opts.optopt("c", "nchecks", "maximum number of checks per test", "nchecks");
    opts.optopt("e", "nequivalents", "number of equivalents", "nequivalents");

    let matches = match opts.parse(&args[1..]) {
        Ok(m) => m,
        Err(f) => panic!(f.to_string()),
    };

    let mutantlen = match matches.opt_str("l") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 10000,
    };
    let nmutants = match matches.opt_str("m") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 10000,
    };
    let ntests = match matches.opt_str("t") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 10000,
    };
    let nfaults = match matches.opt_str("f") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 10,
    };
    let nchecks = match matches.opt_str("c") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 10,
    };
    let nequivalents = match matches.opt_str("e") {
        Some(s) => s.parse().unwrap(),
        None => 0,
    };

    let opts: MyOptions = MyOptions {
        nmutants,
        mutantlen,
        nfaults,
        ntests,
        nchecks,
        nequivalents,
    };
    eprintln!("{:?}", opts);

    fs::create_dir_all(opts.to_string()).unwrap_or_else(|why| {
        println!("! {:?}", why.kind());
    });

    // first generate our tests
    let my_tests = gen_tests(ntests, mutantlen, nchecks);
    // Now generate n mutants
    let mutants = gen_mutants(nmutants, mutantlen, nfaults);

    let equivalents = zeros(nequivalents as usize);

    // how many tests killed this mutant?
    let mutant_kills = mutant_killscore(&opts, &mutants, &equivalents, &my_tests);

    do_statistics(&opts, &mutant_kills);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy). It will automatically tell you of a great number of improvements, such as:

   - Don't use `return` on the last statement.
   - You [shouldn't accept a `&Vec<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).
   - You should use `HashMap::values`
   - `let ref x = y` is not idiomatic, prefer `let x = &y`
2. Many of your function names are very short and `ndlsly_abrvd`. Writing out those extra characters won't hurt.
3. Think a bit more about your code organization. It's a little surprising that you haven't created any methods and everything is currently just loose functions. For example, `gen_tests`, `gen_mutants`, and `do_statistics` all heavily make use of `MyOptions`; perhaps they should actually be methods on `MyOptions` instead?

#### `MyOptions`

1. It's not common to directly implement `ToString`. Instead, implement `Display` as it is more flexible (you can write it to a stream without allocating memory) and [you get `to_string` for free](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#implementors) (`impl<T> ToString for T where T: Display + ?Sized`).
2. On the flip side, it feels wrong to implement either `Display` or `ToString` for `MyOptions` to create a path. A [similar concept](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) exists in the standard library where a helper type is used to provide a more-obvious `Display` implementation.

#### `genbits`

1. `BigUint` implements the `Zero` and `One` traits; using them is much simpler than calling `unwrap`.
2. `Rng::gen_range` is an easier way of constructing a random range. However, `Range` is preferred for multiple generations, but should be hoisted out of the loop.
3. Move the numeric cast into the `Range`.
4. Prefer `fold` to avoid mutable variables and `for` loops.

#### `mutant_killscore`

1. Why does this take `_opts`? If you don't need it, don't pass it.
2. `Iterator::chain` will convert the argument to an iterator, you don't have to call `.iter()` on the argument.

#### `do_statistics`

1. Don't say a function returns `-> ()`; just omit it entirely.
2. Instead of pushing items into a `Vec`, collect them using `Iterator::collect`
3. Are the edits / additions / subtractions really supposed to overlap? They will all be triggerred when `*k == i`.
4. Don't use the `{:}` formatter; it's the same as `{}`.
5. Using `format!` in an `unwrap` or `expect` means the string will be allocated even in success cases. Instead, use `unwrap_or_else` with `panic`.
6. In most cases, you want to use the `write!` / `writeln!` macros instead of direct calls to `write_all`. This also allows you to avoid allocating a string just to write it out, as you can format directly to the file.
7. There's no reason to iterate over the reference to `ntests`, we aren't using the vector anymore after that.
8. In fact, there's no reason to collect `ntests` into a `Vec` at all, you can iterate over it directly.

#### `parse_arguments`

1. Extract argument parsing to a new function, it outweighs the rest of the `main` function.
2. Don't specify the item type of a collection, use `Vec<_>` and let inference handle it.
3. `env::args` already provides `String`s; there's no need to convert.
4. Don't take the reference to `args[0]` if you don't need it.
5. There's boilerplate in the matching of arguments, use `Option::map_or` instead of a `match`.
6. Use a closure to further reduce boilerplate between different arguments.
7. Don't redundantly declare the type of a variable (`let x: Foo = Foo...`).
8. Avoid having multiple authoritative sources for your values (individual variables *and*  the `MyOptions` struct).

#### `main`

1. When creating the directory fails, you print a message and *continue* execution. That seems very suspicious.

---

```
extern crate getopts;
extern crate num_bigint;
extern crate num_traits;
extern crate rand;

use getopts::Options;
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::{One, Zero};
use rand::Rng;
use rand::distributions::{IndependentSample, Range};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::env;
use std::fmt;
use std::fs::{self, File};
use std::io::Write;
use std::iter::repeat;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyOptions {
    mutantlen: u64,
    nmutants: u64,
    ntests: u64,
    nfaults: u64,
    nchecks: u64,
    nequivalents: u64,
}

impl fmt::Display for MyOptions {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "data/mutantlen={:?}/nequivalents={:?}/nmutants={:?}/nfaults={:?}/ntests={:?}/nchecks={:?}/",
            self.mutantlen,
            self.nequivalents,
            self.nmutants,
            self.nfaults,
            self.ntests,
            self.nchecks,
        )
    }
}

fn genbits(bitlen: u64, nflipped: u64) -> BigUint {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let faulty_bits = rng.gen_range(1, nflipped + 1);
    let rr = Range::new(0, bitlen as usize);

    (0..faulty_bits).fold(BigUint::zero(), |m, _| {
        let pos = rr.ind_sample(&mut rng);
        let fault = BigUint::one() << pos;
        m | fault
    })
}

fn gen_lst(num: u64, len: u64, nflipped: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    (0..num).map(|_| genbits(len, nflipped)).collect()
}

fn gen_mutants(nmutants: u64, mutantlen: u64, nfaults: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    gen_lst(nmutants, mutantlen, nfaults)
}

fn gen_tests(ntests: u64, mutantlen: u64, nchecks: u64) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    gen_lst(ntests, mutantlen, nchecks)
}

fn kills(test: &BigUint, mutant: &BigUint) -> bool {
    (test & mutant) > BigUint::zero()
}

fn zeros(size: usize) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    repeat(BigUint::zero()).take(size).collect()
}

fn mutant_killed_by(m: &BigUint, tests: &[BigUint]) -> usize {
    tests.iter().filter(|t| kills(t, m)).count()
}

fn mutant_killscore(
    mutants: &[BigUint],
    equivalents: &[BigUint],
    my_tests: &[BigUint],
) -> HashMap<usize, usize> {
    mutants
        .iter()
        .chain(equivalents)
        .map(|m| mutant_killed_by(m, my_tests))
        .enumerate()
        .collect()
}

fn do_statistics(opts: &MyOptions, mutant_kills: &HashMap<usize, usize>) {
    let ntests = (0..1001).map(|i| {
        let mut e = 0;
        let mut a = 0;
        let mut s = 0;
        for k in mutant_kills.values() {
            if *k == i {
                e += 1;
            }
            if *k >= i {
                a += 1;
            }
            if *k <= i {
                s += 1;
            }
        }
        (i, a, s, e)
    });

    let fname = format!("{}kills.csv", opts);

    let mut f = File::create(&fname).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
        panic!("Unable to create file {}: {}", &fname, e);
    });

    writeln!(f, "ntests, atleast, atmost, exactly").expect("Unable to write data");

    for (i, a, s, e) in ntests {
        writeln!(f, "{}, {}, {}, {}\n", i, a, s, e).expect("Unable to write data");
    }
}

fn parse_arguments() -> MyOptions {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();

    let mut opts = Options::new();
    opts.optopt("l", "mutantlen", "length of a mutant", "mutantlen");
    opts.optopt("m", "nmutants", "number of mutants", "nmutants");
    opts.optopt("t", "ntests", "number of tests", "ntests");
    opts.optopt(
        "f",
        "nfaults",
        "maximum number of faults per mutant",
        "nfaults",
    );
    opts.optopt(
        "c",
        "nchecks",
        "maximum number of checks per test",
        "nchecks",
    );
    opts.optopt("e", "nequivalents", "number of equivalents", "nequivalents");

    let matches = match opts.parse(&args[1..]) {
        Ok(m) => m,
        Err(f) => panic!(f.to_string()),
    };

    let numeric_arg = |name, def| matches.opt_str(name).map_or(def, |s| s.parse().unwrap());

    MyOptions {
        nmutants: numeric_arg("m", 10_000),
        mutantlen: numeric_arg("l", 10_000),
        nfaults: numeric_arg("f", 10),
        ntests: numeric_arg("t", 10_000),
        nchecks: numeric_arg("c", 10),
        nequivalents: numeric_arg("e", 0),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let opts = parse_arguments();
    eprintln!("{:?}", opts);

    fs::create_dir_all(opts.to_string()).unwrap_or_else(|why| {
        println!("! {:?}", why.kind());
    });

    // first generate our tests
    let my_tests = gen_tests(opts.ntests, opts.mutantlen, opts.nchecks);
    // Now generate n mutants
    let mutants = gen_mutants(opts.nmutants, opts.mutantlen, opts.nfaults);

    let equivalents = zeros(opts.nequivalents as usize);

    // how many tests killed this mutant?
    let mutant_kills = mutant_killscore(&mutants, &equivalents, &my_tests);

    do_statistics(&opts, &mutant_kills);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the review, why is using Display recommended instead of ToString? I see that it is commonly done, but coming from other languages where toString()/to_s() is common before print/puts it feels odd.

Comment: Also, I didn't quite understand what you mean when you say " It's a little surprising that there aren't any methods of your own design."

Comment: @rahul I updated the related sections — let me know what else I can improve.

Comment: thank you for the updates, "gen_tests, gen_mutants, and do_statistics all heavily make use of MyOptions" -- they make use of the options, but they are not part of the options.

Comment: @rahul I think that's mostly a matter of naming and how the problem is framed. If the struct were renamed to `Mutations` (or something more applicable) it would make a lot of sense to have such active methods. Perhaps that leads to the idea that `MyOptions` is too big / not factored in an ideal way. For example, if `ntests` and `nchecks` were grouped together in a new `Tests` struct, it could have a method `generate` that takes `mutantlen` as an argument. See how it's simply moving the existing code around to reach for a new type of organization.

Comment: I see. MyOptions at this point has a single cohesive purpose. It stores the preferences of the user. If we split that to test options and mutant options, with a tests class (or do you mean module)? and mutant class? isn't that reducing the cohesion? Any chance you could share a skeleton of how you would organize it?